# Как сделать плавное появление height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Есть такой код CSS:

```
.table-hidden{
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s;

}
.table-visible{
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

и есть такой JS:

```
$('.services__title').click(function () {
    $('.table-hidden').toggleClass('table-visible');
});
```

Хочу сделать плавное появление при `height: auto;`, если задать высоту в пикселях, то всё работает как надо, только вот фиксированная высота не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Лёгкий способ сделать это вместо `height` использовать `max-height`:

```
.table-hidden{
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
}

.table-visible{
    max-height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Крутая штука [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css), примеры анимация тут [DEMO Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), помогает сделать плавные анимации, в добавок ко всему можно туда же к нему засунуть [WOW](https://compnot.ru/frontend/wow-js/) и получить плавные появления блоков и многое другое.